# mapview for shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-mapview

I create an interactive map using `mapView`

the `mapview()` function works fine with my gridded data (`SpatialPixelsDataFrame`):

## Code:

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
library(mapview)
library(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user="root",
                 password="",
                 host="127.0.0.1",
                 dbname="rstudio")
data<-dbReadTable(con,"data")
on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))

data_test <- data
data_test$x <- data$long
data_test$y <- data$lat
coordinates(data_test) = ~x + y
x.range <- as.numeric(c(-5.99, -5.74))  
y.range <- as.numeric(c(35.57, 35.81))  
grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 0.002), 
                   y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 0.002))  # expand points to grid
coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y
gridded(grd) <- TRUE

idw <- idw(formula = temp ~ 1, locations = data_test, newdata = grd)
idw.output = as.data.frame(idw)  # output is defined as a data table

names(idw.output)[1:3] <- c("long", "lat", "temp")
idw.output <- idw.output[,1:3]

coordinates(idw.output) <- ~long+lat
morocco <- readOGR("Data/morocco/TNG", "TNG")
proj4string(idw.output)<-proj4string(morocco)
tempData <- idw.output[morocco,]
proj4string(data_test)<-proj4string(morocco)
gridded(tempData) <- TRUE
m<-mapView(tempData, zcol = "temp") + data_test
m
```

## Result:

[image: working part]

## Now

I want to move to shiny, the problem is that there is no render function for mapview.
I've tried to use fpView() bView() but no result.

## My try with Shiny

### Code:

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(mapview)

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Ardusky")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  # Define UI for application
  fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      mapview:::fpViewOutput("mapplot"),
      mapview:::plainViewOutput("test")
    ))
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="black")
```

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(mapview)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
library(RMySQL)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  repInput <- reactive({
                    con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                                     user="root",
                                     password="",
                                     host="127.0.0.1",
                                     dbname="rstudio")
                    data<-dbReadTable(con,"data")
                    on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))
                    data_test <- data
                    data_test$x <- data$long
                    data_test$y <- data$lat
                    coordinates(data_test) = ~x + y
                    x.range <- as.numeric(c(-5.99, -5.74))  
                    y.range <- as.numeric(c(35.57, 35.81))  
                    grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 0.002), 
                                       y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 0.002))  # expand points to grid
                    coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y
                    gridded(grd) <- TRUE
                    idw <- idw(formula = temp ~ 1, locations = data_test, newdata = grd)
                    idw.output = as.data.frame(idw)  # output is defined as a data table
                    names(idw.output)[1:3] <- c("long", "lat", "temp")
                    idw.output <- idw.output[,1:3]
                    coordinates(idw.output) <- ~long+lat
                    morocco <- readOGR("/home/bloodesu/Data/morocco/TNG", "TNG")
                    proj4string(idw.output)<-proj4string(morocco)
                    tempData <- idw.output[morocco,]
                    proj4string(data_test)<-proj4string(morocco)
                    gridded(tempData) <- TRUE
                    tempData
  })

  output$mapplot <- mapview:::renderfpView({
    mapview:::fpView(repInput(), zcol = "temp")
  })

  output$test <- mapview:::renderPlainView({
    mapview:::plainview(repInput(), zcol = "temp")
  })


})
```

### Result

[image]

## Conclusion

As you can see only the plainView gives some acceptable results but without leaflet support

Comment: I am not very familiar with leafletmap but have you tried `renderLeaflet()`? http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**mapview** and **shiny** are not naturally made for each other. However, **mapview** is based on **leaflet** so we can leverage **shiny** support from **leaflet**. The trick is to set up your map object using **mapview** and then calling the `@map` slot (the **leaflet** part) inside `renderLeaflet()`

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(mapview)

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Ardusky")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  # Define UI for application
  fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("mapplot"),
      mapview:::plainViewOutput("test")
    ))
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="black")
```

**server.ui**

```
library(shiny)
library(mapview)
library(sp)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  data(meuse)
  coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
  proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

  data(meuse.grid)
  coordinates(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
  proj4string(meuse.grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
  gridded(meuse.grid) <- TRUE

  m <- mapview(meuse.grid, zcol = "dist") + meuse

  output$mapplot <- renderLeaflet({
    m@map
  })

})
```

Does this solve your problem?

---

<strike>**UPDATE:**
I have just added `mapviewOutput` and `renderMapview` to the development version on github. This means that we can now skip the explicit call to the `@map` slot of the mapview object. So something like `output$mapplot <- renderMapview(m)` should work now.</strike>

The development version of **mapview** can be installed with `devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop")`

**UPDATE (2018/04/01):**
`renderMapview` and `mapviewOutput` currently do not work! Thus, calling `renderLeaflet({ m@map })` is currently the way to use mapview with shiny.

Comment: m is not reactive so this works, but I'm uncertain the the reactive m() would work. renderLeaflet({ m()@map })  with leafletOutput seems to fail.

Comment: If the reactive returns @map it should work shouldn't it?

Comment: For me, reactive hasn't worked. Only non reactive. I couldn't figure out why.
          output$mapplot <- renderLeaflet({m@map})
..is the way